# How to delete white space in bottom\footer webview in (android)

Tags: java, android, webview, whitespace

**I want when load url in webview in some sites getting unwanted white space in bottom \ footer in webview**

**for example : 5000 pixel height or Much more of 5000 pixel in height webview make**
please sey to me how to work me?

[this image is my problem in webview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBXQ8.jpg)

my XML is :

```
 <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:visibility="visible" />
```

my code is:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            wv.clearCache(true);
            wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wv.setInitialScale(1);
            wv.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0");
            wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

            wv.loadUrl(url);
            wv.setWebViewClient(new Webview1());
            wv.loadUrl("javascript:setResolution(x,y,orientation)");
            wv.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.getContentHeight(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].scrollHeight);");  
        }
    });
```

I searching in net but not find this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be problem in the web page located at the url?